# Broadcasting Celery Tasks is processed by only one Subprocess per Worker

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue, celery, broadcast

**Edit**: In lack of an alternative I just multiply the task. I am using Flask as a webserver. As I call the Train_network endpoint, the Task is executed as many times as there are workers.

```
response = [fw.train_network.delay().get() for _ in range(Workers)]
```

For this to work, I also remove the `-c 2` argument from the `celery worker` command and placed the amount into my config

```
celery.conf.worker_concurrency = cfg.celery_workers
```

Witht his I always know the amount of Subprocesses and how many times the Task should be repeated.

**If there is an better option to solve this, I will update the post with an answer. Or maybe somebody else can provide insight**.

**Edit**: Basically, I need to have access from all Subprocesses to a specific set of variables, which should be shared between these processes. Or, if every process got their own varibale, I need to be able to modify all of these variables by executing a task.

**Edit**:
SO, Ive found out that the Task is indeed broadcasted at to all workers. But not the workers launched from the pool/ the concurrency but fro, the terminal.

So, if I start multiple terminals with `celery worker ..... -c 2` These celery workers do receive the broadcast task. Which is good I guess. Now I want to broadcast these task to the PoolWorkers inside the celery workers too.

Basically I load a model and I want to relaod the model on all pool workers

**Original**:

I"ve been reading trough the user guide cat celery so that I can send a single task to all of my workers.

I am using RabbitMQ and everzthing elso works fine, but the broadcasted task are only processed by a single worker.

I define the exchange and the Queue

```
exchange = Exchange('broadcast_exchange', type='fanout')
celery.conf.task_queues = (Broadcast(name='broadcast_learning', exchange=exchange),)
```

And also the Task routes:

```
celery.conf.task_routes = {
 'fworker.train_network':
    {
        'queue':'broadcast_learning',
        'exchange':'broadcast_exchange'
    },
 ....
}
```

But executing the task with `.delay()` or with `.apply_async(queue='broadcast_learning')` does not seem to send the task to ALL workers - instead only one is processing it.

After starting my worker it listens to the broadcast and the default queue, I see that they are registered in Celery (altough with a strange internal name)

```
[queues]
.> bcast.13bebf5c-f69c-40d9-a0e8-73f74efb9114 exchange=broadcast_exchange(fanout) key=celery
.> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

I already changed from Redis backend to RabbitmQ, since some answers suggested that Redis is not working with broadcasting. But whatever I try, it does not seem to work.

Comment: I got the same problem,  I want to send a broadcast to every working subprocess to reload a config, but it cannot work, only one of subprocess do the work.

Comment: Did you tried to duplicate the Task? response = [fw.train_network.delay().get() for _ in range(Workers)]. Its hacky but works for me

Comment: I have the same problem. It does not work with all subprocesses.